# Android delete directory using Media Store URI

Tags: android, kotlin, android-storage

This is with the new scoped storage.

```
var dlRequest = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(urlToPhoto))
...
var file = File("somedir", filename) // File inside directory "somedir"
dlRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, file.path)
```

So far so good, photos are downloaded into `/Pictures/somedir/`

Now I want to delete the directory and all the files inside. How can I do this?

**Update**: Using scoped storage I have [read here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/10768834-scoped-storage-tutorial-for-android-11-deep-dive) that accessing files via a path is no longer possible, you must use the media store URI. I can get the URI and delete the file, but I still have found no solution to delete the directory.

Comment: Android version of used device?

Comment: You are abusing the File class. The File class is for files. And files have a full path. "somedir/filename" is no full path. Try File.exists(). Better: dlRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, "somedir/filename")

Comment: You cannot delete the directory on Android 11+ as it belongs the download manager. To delete the files use the uries you could obtain from DownloadManager.

Comment: That makes more sense, I am using Android 11. There must be another way to store files in a sub-directory that would allow you to delete the directory afterwards. Or you are saying I will need to save the URI from download manager?

Comment: Yes save all the uries. Can be you can query the media store for them too. Dont know. Just try.

Comment: Did a little test. Could just use File.listFiles() in that directory and delete them. I wonder why you did not even try it.

Comment: How do you know I did not try it? List files always returns 0 files. Without using the deprecated Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory, I have used the applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), which always returns 0 files.

Comment: You can query the media api, that is what I do now and the media store URI is not helpful in deleting the directory.

Comment: getExternalFilesDirs() returns a completely different path. Your files are not there. Makes no sense to use it. Just use getExternalPublicDirectory().

Comment: You can use the mediastore uri i think if you dont just delete but do a createdeleterequest.

Comment: Ive not seen any method to delete directories using the media store URI. If you have an actual solution to the above question that does not use deprecated methods then that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with built-in [deleteRecursively()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/delete-recursively.html) function:

```kotlin
val picturesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
File(picturesDir, "somedir").deleteRecursively()
```

Note that since Android 10, accessing this directory directly has been deprecated.

Comment: And what is somedir in your example code?

Comment: @Coop click the link!

Comment: I understand it is a `File` object. I've been combing through the docs for several hours already and that is one of the first things that comes up in a search, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, your question isn't really on how to delete a directory recursively, but how to find the right path? Then the question title is totally misleading. The documentation of `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` method seems to be very clear on what is the resulting path. I updated my answer. I hope it works, because I didn't have a chance to test it.

Answer (score 0):

FYI

I tested @broot's approach (File.deleteRecursively()) on my production app code, it works fine on my device Android 8.1.

```
val downloadDirectory = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "tancolo")
println("TANCOLO===> download folder = ${downloadDirectory.absolutePath}")
val file = File(downloadDirectory, fileName)
...
```

Obviously, the folder "tancolo" must exist in parent folder "Download", the log shows: `download folder = /storage/emulated/0/Download/tancolo`

And then I used the extension method of deleteRecursively(), like this:

```
//delete the folder "tancolo" and all files in it.
val directory = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "tancolo")
        try {
            val hasDeleted = directory.deleteRecursively()
            println("TANCOLO===> hasDeleted: $hasDeleted")
        } catch (exp: Exception) {
            println("TANCOLO===> exception: ${exp.message}")
        }
```

the log shows:  `TANCOLO===> hasDeleted: true`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the uri list to the Mediastore delete API to delete the
images from it.

If you are deleting images below android 10, then it's very easy with the traditional method.
For android 10 & above, you'll need to take the persisted uri permission of the target directory and then pass the list of the uri to the mediastore's delete method.

You can find many examples to take persistable permission using SAF (Storage Access Framework).
So I am only guiding you through deleting the image files.

Like this,

```
public void deleteAPI29(ArrayList<Media> mediaList) {
        DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions().get(0).getUri());
        for (int i = 0; i < mediaList.size(); i++) {
            File file = new File(mediaList.get(i).getPath());
            DocumentFile nextDocument = documentFile.findFile(file.getName());
            try {
                DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(getContentResolver(), nextDocument.getUri());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

For android 11,

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    private void deleteAPI30(ArrayList<Media> mediaList, Context context) throws IntentSender.SendIntentException {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

        List<Uri> uriList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mediaList.size(); i++) {
            uriList.add(mediaList.get(i).getAppendedIdUri());
        }
        Collections.addAll(uriList);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(contentResolver, uriList);
        ((Activity) context).startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                DELETE_REQUEST_CODE, null, 0,
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION, 0, null);
    }
```

You can check if images are deleted or not by observing the result in 'onActivityResult' method.

That's it! Hope it will get your job done easily.